# Reverse all line of text in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I have a file where I have multiple lines. Is there an option in Sublime Text 3 to reverse whole line ? Like

```
ABCDEFG
```

to

```
GFEDCBA
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not inside Sublime Text, but in Linux/OSX the [rev command-line utility](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rev) does just that - `rev file.txt` reverses every line of the file.

Answer (score 52):

## if someone  need to do the  following operation.

```
12345
67890
abcde
  |
  to
  |
  v

abcde
67890
12345
```

click **Edit---->Permute lines--->Reverse** and it will reverse all lines you selected in a file.

Answer (score 24):

You best bet would definitely to take Leonid's advice and use a different tool, but if you are curious as to how one might do that in Sublime you have two options.

---

First go to Tools->New Plugin and paste the following code into the file:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class ReverseCharactersCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        for region in self.view.sel():
            stringContents = self.view.substr(region)
            self.view.replace(edit, region, stringContents[::-1])
```

Following that select the different sections of the document that you want reversed and run the follow command from the console

```
view.run_command("reverse_characters")
```

Here is an image of that workflow.

[image]

The import section of that code is the:

```
stringContents[::-1]
```

Which is an idiomatic way of reversing a string in Python.

---

Alternatively you could go checkout this follow git repository and which has the same code and a convenient command palette options specified for you :)

https://github.com/MattSeen/ST_ReverseCharacters

Comment: Any way to make a keycombo to trigger this instead of using ```view.run_command("reverse_characters")```?

Answer (score 15):

In vanilla sublime:

1. Select the text to reverse
2. Open the Find menu (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>)

   - Ensure "In selection" and "Regular expression" options are enabled
3. Search for `.` and click "Find all" (<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)

   - Now each character of the selection is highlighted with its own cursor.
4. Click `Edit > Permute selections > Reverse`

It's not elegant but it is straightforward and repeatable. If you already have the cursors, all you need is step 4.